# Uncertainty principle - single slit diffraction - one particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, diffraction

In reference to this diagram:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html

Let x be the horizontal axis and y be the vertical axis. We make the slit width arbitrarily small.

Assume the slit is located at
$$(x,y) = (0,0)$$

Assume the detection screen is at $$x=D$$

So we send a single particle through the slit. It passes through the slit at $t_1$ and hits the screen at $t_2$ at some y value $H$

So we know the particle's position at both times
$$(x_{t_1},y_{t_1}) = (0,0)$$
$$(x_{t_2},y_{t_2}) = (D,H)$$

So we calculate $v_x, v_y$ at $t_1$

$$v_x = \frac{D}{t_2-t_1}$$
$$v_y = \frac{H}{t_2-t_1}$$

We seem to be able to get both position and velocity of the particle at a particular time to arbitrary precision. But I thought the uncertainty principle was supposed to prevent this... so where am I going wrong here? Please note this is just a single particle with a pair of measurements at $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Your are not using the quantum mechanics formalism to model your problem. If you consider a particle in a classical way (I.e. not a representation with a wave function) you will not be able to expose a quantum principle such as Heisenberg's uncertainty principle!
In classical physics, it is possible to know both the velocity and position with precision at the same time.

The uncertainty principle comes from the mathematical formalism used to describe quantum mechanics. This is related to Fourier transform (see https://youtu.be/MBnnXbOM5S4). Also, yes this principle is verified experimentally with - for example - this same slit experiment (see https://youtu.be/MBnnXbOM5S4) and interpreting this experiment (and thus demonstarting the uncertainty principle) requires the quantum mechanics formalism.

In other words, understanding and explaining Heisenberg's uncertainty principle requires a more complex description of the system than the one used in your reasoning.

Comment: But the uncertainty principle is an experimental fact isn't it? So isn't it demonstrable by experiment?

Comment: In this experiment, you measure the position using the slit and then the momentum with the projection on the screen. So your uncertainties (or precision) is determined by the width of the slit and the size of the pattern on the screen.

Comment: But there's only one particle here. It goes through the slit and then hits the screen. There's no pattern.

Comment: Yes! And all the uncertainty lies in the fact that the more you reduce the width of the slit the wider will be the area on the screen where the particle can fall. If you repeat the experiment several times, the pattern will emerge. You have to understand that the particle is described by a probability distribution (wave function) and once you measure it (when it falls on the screen) the "collapsing of the wave function" occurs and the particle will hit in only one point. However, because of heisenberg's principle you cannot predict this exact point where the particle will end up.